# Type.GetType() not working for F# type in C# code

Tags: reflection, f#, c#-to-f#

I have an F# assembly called Assembly1

I have the following module:

```
namespace Assembly1

module MyModule =
   type MyClass(x: int, y: int) =
   new() = MyClass(0, 0)
```

In a C# assembly that references this F# assembly, the following code gives me a value of 'null' back:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("Assembly1.MyModule.MyClass, Assembly1");
```

Is what I am trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've put `MyClass` into a module, it's compiled as a nested class. Its name is `Assembly1.MyModule+MyClass`.

From C#, you should be able to load it like this:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("Assembly1.MyModule+MyClass, Assembly1");
```

If you don't want to have nested classes (which are generally frowned upon in C#), you can define it directly in a namespace:

```
namespace Assembly1.LibraryXyz

type MyClass(x: int, y: int) = class end
```

This class will have the name `Assembly1.LibraryXyz.MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

To add to [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276541/68457), it's also worth noting that a lot of modules in F# are represented by different names in IL (and therefore non-F# languages) than they appear with in F# itself.

For example, this piece of code:

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let private core =
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    |> Seq.find (fun a -> a.GetName().Name = "FSharp.Core")

let private seqMod =
    core.GetTypes()
    |> Seq.filter FSharpType.IsModule
    |> Seq.find (fun t -> 
                   t.FullName = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule")
```

Will find the Seq module in FSharp.Core.

The FSharp.Reflection namespace has a bunch of helper methods to make working with F# specific types with System.Reflection a little bit less painful, so it's worth loading up a couple of assemblies in FSI and having a play with those if you're going to be doing a lot of reflection work with F# code.

You can create modules with "mismatching" names like this yourself using the [CompiledName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee340493%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute - this is especially useful for those times where you want a type and a module with the same name. The normal convention (as shown with the Seq type/module) is to annotate the module with Compiled name.

```
[<CompiledName("MyTypeModule")>]
module MyType =
    let getString m =
        match m with
        | MyType s -> s
```